# ¿Cómo calcular la edad del usuario a partir de su fecha de nacimiento en PHYTON?

Tags: python

### Lo intente así, pero me sale error

Recibo el input desde el usuario en formato aaaa/mm/dd

```py
while True:
    fecha_str = input('\n Ingrese fecha "aaaa/mm/dd"...: ')
    try:
        fecha = datetime.strptime(fecha_str, '%Y/%m/%d').strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
        print("\n Tu fecha es: ")
        print(str(fecha))
    except ValueError:
        print("\n No ha ingresado una fecha correcta...")
    else:
        break

years=date.today()-fecha_str
return years
```

Comment: Hola @paula bienvenida a [es.so] mira [ask], adicionalmente ¿podrías formatear tu código para que se muestre de forma correcta? ya que del modo en el que está actualmente resulta difícil de comprender, esto lo puedes hacer encapsulando tu código entre `\`\`\`<tu código>\`\`\``. También sería bueno que aclararás cuál es el error que obtienes al ejecutar tu código. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta en cualquier momento. Adicional, te invito a realizar el [tour] y ganar tu primera medalla.

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema esta en que conviertes la fecha a *string* por lo que luego no podrás operar, otro problema que presentaras son los años bisiestos. Te presentare las 2 soluciones, la primera será si no te importa los años bisiestos y la otra tomándolos en cuenta.

```py
#tienes que importar asi
from datetime import datetime, date

#fecha actual
ahora =datetime.now()

while True: 
  fecha_str = input('\n Ingrese fecha "aaaa/mm/dd"...: ') 
  try: 
    fecha = datetime.strptime(fecha_str, '%Y/%m/%d')
    fecha_str = fecha.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') 
    print(f'\n Tu fecha es: {fecha_str}')  
  except ValueError: 
    print("\n No ha ingresado una fecha correcta...") 
  else: 
    break

#dias
user_days =ahora-fecha
user_days = user_days.days

#obteniendo años
years = user_days//365
print(f'tienes {years} años')
```

**Probamos**

```
Ingrese fecha "aaaa/mm/dd"...: 2019/01/01

Tu fecha es: 01-01-2019
tienes 2 años
```

Para tener en cuenta los años bisiestos nos ayudaremos del modulo `dateutil`. Instalamos `pip install python-dateutil`

```py
#tienes que importar asi
from datetime import datetime, date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

#fecha actual
ahora =datetime.now()

while True: 
  fecha_str = input('\n Ingrese fecha "aaaa/mm/dd"...: ') 
  try: 
    fecha = datetime.strptime(fecha_str, '%Y/%m/%d')
    fecha_str = fecha.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') 
    print(f'\n Tu fecha es: {fecha_str}')  
  except ValueError: 
    print("\n No ha ingresado una fecha correcta...") 
  else: 
    break
#utilizamos el modulo para restar correctamente
edad = relativedelta(ahora, fecha_nacimiento)
print(f"Felicidades! tienes {edad.years} años, {edad.months} meses y {edad.days} días")
```

**Probamos**

```
Ingrese fecha "aaaa/mm/dd"...: 2019/01/01

Tu fecha es: 01-01-2019
Felicidades! tienes 2 años, 4 meses y 21 días
```

En este caso se tiene 2 años 4 meses y 21 dias :)